# SQL Server to MySql conversion - sysobjects

Tags: mysql, sql-server, mysql-workbench

I am trying to convert the below SQL Server code into MySql...

```
  SELECT 
        columns  = COALESCE(columns + ',', '') + Cast(sc.name AS char(64))
  FROM 
        sysColumns sc 
  INNER JOIN 
        sysObjects so ON sc.ID = so.ID
  WHERE 
        so.type = 'u'; AND 
        so.name = tableName;
```

Is there any tool or reference link for this conversion?

I found I can use `all_source` for `sysObjects` but not sure what to use for `sysColumns` and `tableName`.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be99e/8)

**MySQL 5.5.30 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `label` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `level` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `path` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `sortorder` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT t.table_name,
  group_concat( c.column_name ORDER BY c.ordinal_position ) AS columns
FROM information_schema.tables t
  JOIN  information_schema.columns c ON t.table_name = c.table_name
WHERE t.table_name = 'category'
GROUP BY t.table_name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be99e/8/0)**:

```
| TABLE_NAME |                                 COLUMNS |
--------------------------------------------------------
|   category | id,parent_id,label,level,path,sortorder |
```

Comment: Hi,
Thank you I will try this code
How to I change the below MsSal Code to MySql


`IF (SELECT OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(@tableName), 'TableHasIdentity')) = 1 
-- Has identity column
  SET @sql = 'SET IDENTITY_INSERT '+@tableName+' ON ' + @sql_insert
ELSE
  SET @sql = @sql_insert`

Is there any approch or url which I refer to see MsSql equivalent functions in MySql

Comment: @trip, i am not ready just now answer you, post this as question to allow more people see it